# Two returns in Closures

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm New to `swift` here. Was reading closures on `weheartswift`. There is one section talking about capturing value. Two questions here:

1. How do I understand the two returns here?
2. Why this closure captures the previous value from variable, shouldn't i be initialized every time from the value of start, which is always 0?

Code :

```
func makeIterator(start: Int, step: Int) -> () -> Int {

    var i = start

    return {
        i += step
        return i
    }
}

var iterator = makeIterator(0, 1)

iterator() // 1

iterator() // 2

iterator() // 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var i = start
return /*the following is a closure that returns an Int:*/{
    i += step
    return i
}/*< end of closure*/
```

What's being returned is a closure. `{ return i }` is actually a function that returns the value of `i`.

You could also write it this way:

```
func makeIterator(start: Int, step: Int) -> () -> Int {

    var i = start
    func iterate() -> Int {
        i += step
        return i
    }
    return iterate
}
```

A closure is **functionality + state**. The "state" here is the local variable `i`.

The closure "closes over" `i`, meaning that each time the closure is executed it will be looking at the same `i` which it can modify. This is true **even after the closure is returned from the function**. When you call it multiple times, it updates its internal state and returns the new value.

Comment: I see, so basiclly, the var i = start happens in the var iterator = makeIterator(0, 1) stage, later on, all things happens in that two line closure when I call the iterator.

Answer (score -1):

It is seems like function returns function as its value. returned function doesn't take any argument and returns a integer value. I recommend you to have a look at Swift documentation.